# Where and how to put inline js in pages

Tags: functions, javascript

On the Web there are many articles on how to insert external scripts into a document using the `wp_enqueue_script()` *method*.

Among the articles I couldn't find anything explanaining how to add inline, `<script>` tag enclosed scripts.

I use `<script>` tags in the middle of my documents though I suppose doing so is not the most elegant way. There should be a better way to add arbitrary scripts so the code is automatically moved in the head or the footer. Is there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wp enqueue inline script due to dependancies](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/wp-enqueue-inline-script-due-to-dependancies)

Comment: ehm it's a quite old question you know? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add inline js by using the **wp_add_inline_script** function.

```
function prince_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'prince-script', get_template_directory_uri(). 'main.js');

    $hide_on_mobile = apply_filters( 'prince_hide_on_mobile', true );

    $data = 'var hideOnMobile = ' . ( $hide_on_mobile ? 'true': 'false' ) . ';';

    wp_add_inline_script( 'prince-script', $data, 'before' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prince_scripts');
```

Comment: `wp_add_inline_script` is meant to add JavaScript that configures another script, that's why you need to first run `wp_enqueue_script`, and then run run `wp_add_inline_script` referencing the other main script that was enqueued.

Answer (score 10):

I'm looking at the Twenty Seventeen `functions.php` source code right now and they left a pattern in there for inlining `script` (or anything for that matter) into the document with priority, shown here generalized using a named function:

```
function add_inline_script() {
  echo "<script>/* do awesome things */</script>\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_inline_script', 0 );
```

You might want to do this, for example, if you are loading an `async` script like the *alternative* Google Analytics [async tracking snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), enabling you to kick off **non-blocking script requests** as soon as the document starts getting parsed (if placed above blocking requests).

Besides `async`, modern browsers also allow us to [manage async dependencies](https://habdas.org/post/managing-async-dependencies-javascript/) leveraging the [Fetch API](https://devdocs.io/dom/fetch_api/using_fetch), affording one the ability to **load external dependencies** asynchronously in parallel without risking a race condition.

The following image and example illustrate using this technique to reduce page load time by [loading scripts without blocking](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/) in the [Twenty Eleven theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/) using [Fetch Inject](https://codeberg.org/vhs/fetch-inject):

[image: Loading Twenty Seventeen with Fetch Injection]
**Figure 1:** Twenty Seventeen theme scripts plus `lazysizes` loading asynchronously in parallel.

Piggybacking on a [question about string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676417/should-i-use-curly-brackets-or-concatenate-variables-within-strings). Use it while dropping **arbitrary blocks of content** into the page with `echo` using NOWDOC or HEREDOC and `global` assignments and string interpolation with Fetch Inject, as shown here:

```
/**
 * Load scripts using Fetch Inject instead of wp_enqueue_script
 * for for faster page loads and lower perceived latency.
 *
 * @since WordCamp Ubud 2017
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/263733/117731
 * @link https://github.com/jhabdas/fetch-inject
 *
 */
function add_inline_script() {
  $twentyseventeen_l10n = array(
    'quote' => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'quote-right' ) ),
    'expand' => __( 'Expand child menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
    'collapse' => __( 'Collapse child menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
    'icon' => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'angle-down', 'fallback' => true ) )
  );
  $jquery_script_path = '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4';
  $jquery_dependent_script_paths = [
    get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/global.js' ),
    get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.js' ),
    get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js' ),
    get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/navigation.js' )
  ];
  $lazysizes_path = get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/lazysizes.min.js' );
  $screen_reader_text_object_name = 'twentyseventeenScreenReaderText';
  $twentyseventeen_l10n_data_json = json_encode($twentyseventeen_l10n);
  $jquery_dependent_script_paths_json = json_encode($jquery_dependent_script_paths);
  $inline_script = <<<EOD
window.{$screen_reader_text_object_name} = $twentyseventeen_l10n_data_json;
(function () {
  'use strict';
  if (!window.fetch) return;
  /**
   * Fetch Inject v1.6.8
   * Copyright (c) 2017 Josh Habdas
   * @licence ISC
   */
  var fetchInject=function(){"use strict";const e=function(e,t,n,r,o,i,c){i=t.createElement(n),c=t.getElementsByTagName(n)[0],i.type=r.blob.type,i.appendChild(t.createTextNode(r.text)),i.onload=o(r),c?c.parentNode.insertBefore(i,c):t.head.appendChild(i)},t=function(t,n){if(!t||!Array.isArray(t))return Promise.reject(new Error("`inputs` must be an array"));if(n&&!(n instanceof Promise))return Promise.reject(new Error("`promise` must be a promise"));const r=[],o=n?[].concat(n):[],i=[];return t.forEach(e=>o.push(window.fetch(e).then(e=>{return[e.clone().text(),e.blob()]}).then(e=>{return Promise.all(e).then(e=>{r.push({text:e[0],blob:e[1]})})}))),Promise.all(o).then(()=>{return r.forEach(t=>{i.push({then:n=>{"text/css"===t.blob.type?e(window,document,"style",t,n):e(window,document,"script",t,n)}})}),Promise.all(i)})};return t}();
  fetchInject(
    $jquery_dependent_script_paths_json
  , fetchInject([
    "{$jquery_script_path}"
  ]));
    fetchInject(["{$lazysizes_path}"])
})();
EOD;
  echo "<script>{$inline_script}</script>";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_inline_script', 0);
```

Reduces perceived latency on a stock Twenty Seventeen theme by ~50 percent. Can be applied to any theme.

How does it work?

- Replaces **all** of the scripts enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script` so they output faster by using Fetch Injection. (Note: See Fetch Inject docs for backwards browser compatibility with older browsers.)
- Uses HEREDOC to output everything in a `script` tag in the `head`.
- Defines a window Global the theme wants.
- Loads all of the scripts asynchronously in parallel as shown in the above image, but waits for jQuery to finish loading before executing the dependencies (already downloaded).
- Does all the work in an IIFE to prevent any free variables from leaking into the `window` scope.

HEREDOC is ideal for controlling output when you need to maintain copyright notices or other formatting via mixed templates. It also helps increase script debugging speed when you don't have the minified code handy or just want to lob something into the document for testing purposes.

If you want to ensure items are only added one time, see this answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131640/117731

Finally, if you wanted to **add to the footer** instead of the head, you can replace `wp_head` in the `add_action` call with `wp_footer`.

**EDIT:** After some more digging I found [this post](https://davidwalsh.name/wp_head) on David Walsh's blog, suggesting at least simple inlining has been available since at least 2012. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is the only way that javascript should ever be added to your site. It allows you and other plugins to declare dependencies and even deregister scripts if needed. As mentioned on [a different thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50624/settings-to-get-the-most-out-of-w3-total-cache/50639#comment66262_50639) today, caching plugins can't gzip or minify your scripts if you don't use the proper WordPress technique.

If you look at the codex page, you'll see that you can control whether the script is in the header or footer.

Comment: i noticed that the `<script>` was cancelled by stackoverflow security system. Now my question should be more clear. I'm speaking about inline scripts that needs to know what's inside the page.

Comment: Doesn't answer OP or consider real world use cases for things like `admin_enqueue_scripts`, `login_enqueue_scripts` or scripts as part of shortcodes which need to wait for the `wp_footer`. Or `enqueue_embed_scripts`, which [are intended](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/419c8d97ce8df7d5004ee0b566bc5e095f0a6ca8/wp-includes/embed.php#L845-L846) for use by plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Even though mrwweb is correct and that technique should be used, in reality nothing is perfect and there are times when inline scripts and styles are used. You can use `wp script is` to check for a script and output them in the header or footer using `wp_head` or `wp_footer`.

You can refer to scribu's answer in this post, [wp enqueue inline script due to dependancies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/wp-enqueue-inline-script-due-to-dependancies)

Comment: So basically Scribu suggest to just print it in the footer via the wp_footer action?

Comment: also the wp_localize_script is to be considered

Comment: If needed, yes.